# Angular validate form with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Typically to validate a form in Angular, I would use something like this on the `ng-submit` directive:

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="formName.$valid && submitForm()"></form>
```

This works great when the form has a name that I set myself while building the form.  However, in my current situation, I am trying to create multiple forms based on a list of objects.  In this case, each form has a name that is determined on the fly.

When the user submits one of these forms, how can I validate it before running the `submitForm()` function for that form?

Here's a jsfiddle of the simplified problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/ub6wLewc/1/

My question is, how can I access the name of the form in order to validate it? Here is the code from the fiddle:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("AppController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.forms = [{
    id: 1,
    value: "val1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    value: "val2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    value: "val3"
  }];

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    alert('submitted');
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <div class="formWrapper" ng-repeat="form in forms">
    <form name="{{ 'form' + form.id }}" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
      <input ng-model="form.value" required />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use `this` to access the scope in your templates.

```html
{{this.foo === foo}} <!-- This will always show "true" -->
```

Therefore, you can simply use `this[myDynamicFormName]` to access the form:

```
<form name="{{'form' + form.id}}" ng-submit="this['form' + form.id].$valid && submitForm()"></form>
```

Comment: Two for one special.

Comment: You can also alias it to a scope variable by placing this inside the form element:
`<p hidden ng-init="htmlForm=this['form' + form.id]"></p>`

Comment: Note you cannot use hyphenated names for this to work properly